# Position absolute and overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow, css-position

We have two DIVs, one embedded in the other. If the outer DIV is not positioned absolute then the inner DIV, which is positioned absolute, does not obey the overflow hidden of the outer DIV.

```css
#first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#second {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any chance to make the inner DIV obey the overflow hidden of the outer DIV without setting the outer DIV to position absolute (cause that will muck up our complete layout)?
Also position relative for our inner DIV isn't an option as we need to "grow out" of a table TD.

```css
#first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

#second {
    width: 50px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table id="first">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="second"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 371, accepted):

Make outer `<div>` to `position: relative` and inner `<div>` to `position: absolute`. It should work for you.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I always thought position:relative is the default. I just learned that static is the default. I accept shankhans answer as both answers are equivalent and shankhan needs some more points ;-)

Comment: Some explanation and/or documentation would be a great addition.

Comment: FYI : Of course, you need to put overflow:hidden on position:relative div

Answer (score 32):

What about `position: relative` for the outer div? In the example that hides the inner one. It also won't move it in its layout since you don't specify a top or left.

Answer (score 26):

An absolutely positioned element is actually positioned regarding a `relative` parent, or the nearest found relative parent. So the element with `overflow: hidden` should be between `relative` and `absolute` positioned elements:

```
<div class="relative-parent">
  <div class="hiding-parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.relative-parent {
  position:relative;
}
.hiding-parent {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.child {
  position:absolute; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure.

1. parent position relative.
2. parent have manually assigned width and height(important as child element having absolute position).
3. child position absolute;

```css
.outer{
   position:relative;
   width:200px; 
   height:100px;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.inner{
   position:absolute;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   font-size:3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class=inner>
Inner DIV to apply overflw hidden
</div>
</div>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue with a radial background gradient. If the above solutions clip parts of your element, just apply the position relative to the html body instead of a direct parent.

```
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You just make `div`s like this:

```
<div style="width:100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid; overflow:hidden; ">
    <br/>
    <div style="position:inherit; width: 200px; height:200px; background:yellow;">
        <br/>
        <div style="position:absolute; width: 500px; height:50px; background:Pink; z-index: 99;">
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this code will help you :)