# position absolute and overflow hidden

Tags: css, position

I am not able to make the overflow hidden(horizontally) take effect when I apply the position property. there are several posts(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605715/position-absolute-and-overflow-hidden)) which are asking the same, but their solutions does not work for me, would anybody please take a look at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mwxzT/2/)?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set a width to the absolutely positioned element and position relative the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/DOSBeats/mwxzT/7/