# How to show JQPlot Bar Chart in a Scrollable Div

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I want to Show horizontal scrollbar in the DIV in which Chart is present, but irrespective of any size I assign to the container DIV, the Chart control takes up all the space. This is the code I am using.

```
 <div id="chart1" style="height: 230px; width: 355px; overflow: scroll; padding-left: 10px;"></div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6GZI.png

As visible from the image, either it shows both scrollbars and if I set overflow-x:true and overflow-y: hidden, then it shows the horizontal scroll, but disabled.

Any help please?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605715/position-absolute-and-overflow-hidden

Comment: use an extra div, one for the chart, one to set scroll. Chart div goes inside scroll element

Comment: This is the change I did in code : <div style="height: 230px; position: relative; width: 355px;">
                            <div id="chart1" style="height: 230px; padding-left: 10px; position: absolute; width: 655px;"></div>  </div> But still external div is not showing.

Comment: Solved it by this code :      <div style="height: 230px; width: 480px; padding-left: 10px; overflow: scroll;">
                            <div id="chart1" style="height: 200px; width: 655px;"></div> 
                        </div>