# Hide Overflow of multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vis.js

I want to create a web site that contains a network graph. I used vis.js for this. If you hover over an image of a person the image should flip and show some information on the background. I created a JavaScript file that creates a tree out of a json file dynamically. Here is a picture of the result: [image]

As you can see the images are visible outside the box which should not be the case. They should not be displayed outside of the borders.

Here is my html-code:

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section " id="section0">
    ...
</div>
<div class="section" id="section1">
    ...
</div>
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="intro">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="media">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section active" id="section3">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <div id="network_container_1">
            <div id="network"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide active" id="slide2">
        <div id="network_container_2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    #network{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        
    }
    #network_container_bewohner{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        border:1px black solid;
    }

    #network_container_freunde{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 4px;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    #slide1{
        z-index:0;
    }
    #slide2{
        z-index:1;
    }
```

The images are located as #block1, #block2, #block3, etc. as class overlay inside of #network_container_1.
As you can see I tried to mess around with the z-index but it doesn't work.

Comment: `#fullPage.section { overflow:hidden; }`

Comment: DO you have a CDN for vis.js and the JS code?

Comment: No I don't have a CDN unfortunately

Comment: #fullPage.section { overflow:hidden; } doesn't work

Comment: What element is the box that should have its overflow hidden?

Comment: it's the id "network_container_1". I tried this "#network_container_1{ overflow:hidden; }" but it doesn't work. Maybe it's because the position of the overlay class is absolute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. The problem was the absolute position.
See here: [Position absolute and overflow hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605715/position-absolute-and-overflow-hidden)

Comment: please accept your answer to indicated the issue is solved