# Form.IO - How to make dropdown choices inside a DataGrid to become visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, formio

I'm using [Form.IO JS library](https://github.com/formio/formio.js) for developing a new form. I need to create a DataGrid with 11 components inside of it, so the only way to fit everything inline is to use `overflow: auto` CSS rule (in fact `overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden`). 
Here comes the issue. Because of those 2 CSS rules, when I open a `select` component, the opened list choices become visible **inside** the DataGrid component, which I don't want to because it hides all choices. I played around with `z-index`, but without luck .

[image]

Can someone guide me on how to successfully show the dropdown choices **outside** of the DataGrid? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old and wierd CSS question that we read about from time to time.

Basically, you need to:

- create a *wrapper box* that is a *common ancestor* to both the box with `overflow-y: hidden` and your `select` list. This wrapper has to be [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- give a `position: absolute` positioning to the box that contains the list of your dropdown options (i.e. the list that has to *bypass* the `overflow-y: hidden` declaration)
- ensure that the list **HAS NOT** any *positioned* ancestor before the wrapper.

After all that, especially if you're using a third-party library that comes with its own css files, you will almost certainly need to tweak a bit with the library's default css rules.

Here a snippet (using the [Fomantic-UI](https://fomantic-ui.com/) library and components):

```js
$('#selection').dropdown();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;  /* "positioned" common ancestor to list and overflow hidden box */
}

.long--box {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#selection.ui.selection.dropdown .menu {
  width: 196px;
  max-width: 196px;
  min-width: 196px;
  top: 58px;
  left: 21px;
  position: absolute; /* absolute positioning for the list */
  z-index: 10;
}

#selection.ui.selection.dropdown {
  width: 196px;
  transform: none;
  position: static !important; /* no positioning for the list parent (the first "positioned" one has to be the common ancestor)*/
}

input {
  height: 36px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.8/semantic.min.js"></script>



<body>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='long--box'>
      <div class='ui selection dropdown' id='selection'>
        <div class='default text'>Select...</div>

        <div class='menu'>
          <div class="item" data-value="0">Cat</div>
          <div class="item" data-value="1">Dog</div>
          <div class="item" data-value="2">Bird</div>
          <div class="item" data-value="3">Rabbit</div>
          <div class="item" data-value="4">Squirrel</div>
          <div class="item" data-value="5">Horse</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='ui input'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input">
      </div>

      <div class='ui input'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input">
      </div>

      <div class='ui input'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input">
      </div>

      <div class='ui input'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input">
      </div>

      <div class='ui input'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input">
      </div>

      <div class='ui input'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

###### Some other useful links about your question:

- [Position absolute and overflow hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605715/position-absolute-and-overflow-hidden)
- [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue)
- https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/